# Making an opponent object using a class not working properly; they don't display on the screen for some reason?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

So a while ago I learned how to create a class for which had the purpose of creating an "opponent" which would basically fight the player and etc. It was a good tutorial and while I did learn how to create this type of class, I also got issues from the code itself when testing it out.

One of the reasons it didn't work properly was because of flipping my sprites horizontally; I have 2 sprite variables, 1 that loads the images and the other which is supposed to contain a list. A loop then "flips" all the images from the original and stores it inside the empty list. This, however, caused an issue and started to make my sprite "flash" on the screen in both directions so I removed the loop, tried again and it worked but this time it only had one sprite(facing the left).
I also tried to remove the variables and the loop outside the class but that ended up not displaying the image at all.

```
#Goku Black
walkLeftGB = [ pygame.image.load("GB1.png"), pygame.image.load("GB2.png"), pygame.image.load("GB3.png"), pygame.image.load("GB4.png") ]
walkRightGB = []

for l in walkLeftGB:
    walkRightGB.append(pygame.transform.flip(l, True, False))

for x in range(len(walkLeftGB)):
    walkLeftGB[x] = pygame.transform.smoothscale(walkLeftGB[x], (372, 493))

for x in range(len(walkRightGB)):
    walkRightGB[x] = pygame.transform.smoothscale(walkRightGB[x], (372, 493))

# === CLASSES === (CamelCase names)

class Enemy(object):
    global vel
    global walkCount1
    global walkRightGB, walkLeftGB

    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, end):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.end = end
        self.path = [self.x, self.end]
        self.walkCount1 = 0
        self.vel = 3
        self.walkLeftGB = walkLeftGB
        self.walkRightGB = walkRightGB

    def draw(self, DS):
        self.move()
        global walkCount1
        if self.walkCount1 + 1 <= 33:
            self.walkCount1 = 0

        if self.vel > 0:
            DS.blit(self.walkRightGB[self.walkCount1 //4], (self.x, self.y))
            self.walkCount1 += 1
        else: 
            DS.blit(self.walkLeftGB[self.walkCount1 //4], (self.x, self.y))
            self.walkCount1 += 1


    def move(self):   
        global walkCount1
        if self.vel > 0:
            if self.x + self.vel < self.path[1]:
                self.x += self.vel
            else:
                self.vel = self.vel * -1
                self.walkCount1 = 0
        else:
            if self.x - self.vel > self.path[0]:
                self.x += self.vel
            else:
                self.vel = self.vel * -1
                self.walkCount1 = 0


man = Enemy(1600, 407, 96, 136, 22)

def redrawGameWindow():
    global walkCount
    pygame.display.update()
    man.draw(DS)
    DS.blit(canyon,(0,0))
    lastMoved = "left"
    if walkCount + 1 >= 27:
        walkCount = 0
    if left:
        DS.blit(walkLeft[walkCount//3],(x,y))
        walkCount +=1
        lastMoved = "left"
    elif right:
        DS.blit(walkRight[walkCount//3], (x,y))
        walkCount +=1
        lastMoved = "right"
    else: #this is when its moving neither left or right
        if lastMoved == "left":
            DS.blit(char2, (x, y))
        else:
            DS.blit(char, (x, y))   

#The "redrawGameWindow" is then called in a loop inside a function.
```

After I made those changes mentioned above, the output received was now the image not appearing at all, I expected the output for the image to appear(and maybe move)

Answer (score 1):

This does not appear to do what you want it to:

```
        if self.walkCount1 + 1 <= 33:
            self.walkCount1 = 0
```

As a detail, it's weird to add one and compare to 33, when `if self.walkCount1 <= 32` would suffice.

More importantly, it looks like you wanted `>=` there.

You have some hard-coded [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) divisors: `// 3` and `// 4`.
Rather than e.g. 4, it would be much better to
refer to `len(self.walkRightGB)`.
Then you could choose to insert new interpolated walking images,
or delete some, without having to worry about correctness of
other code that may be affected.
Numbers like 27 should *also* be expressed in more meaningful terms.

It's not clear to me you want `//` integer division.
Possibly you were looking for `%` modulo instead.
As written, it looks like there's a danger of the code
trying to access past the end of an image array.

Printing out the counts would help you to debug this,
for example by verifying that incremented count is preserved
across function calls.